# cannot Install Angular2 app using Cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

- i followed link; https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki
- npm version:5.0.1
- node version:6.11.0
- i run command

  ```
     npm install -g @angular/cli
  ```

solution i tried

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

but it doesn't work for me .

does it is npm bug or angular2.
[image]

please suggest.

error

```
unexpected end of input at 1:13267
```

i also tried with ;https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html.

- npm install not working
  [image]

Comment: follow this https://medium.com/@julyseven2002/how-to-install-angular-2-using-cli-on-windows-7-machine-e328199f4e5a i think it will helpfull

Comment: see [this issue also](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1045)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to uninstall wrong packages by:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli          # Remove global package
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli  # Remove from package.json

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli         # Remove global package
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli # Remove from package.json

rm -rf node_modules dist # Use rmdir on Windows
npm cache clean
```

And now:

```
 npm install npm@latest -g                   #update npm
 npm install -g @angular/cli@latest          # Global package
 npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest  # Local package
 npm install                                 # Restore removed dependencies
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Comment: thanks mobile32 you save my day i hope these commands may solve all user problem